# How do I get this child element with overflow auto to show when the parent is overflow hidden?

Tags: html, css, overflow

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y8gxygt0/)

As you can see I'm trying to create a full screen overlay navigation. I have set the body height to 200%, and when the overlay nav shows I set the body to `overflow: hidden;`.

I've also set the important overlay navigation properties to:

```
.flexbar .overlay-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 150%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I set the height 150% for test purposes on the off-chance that there are more menu items than the screen can show on smaller screens. I want the user to be able to scroll within the overlay navigation, but for some reason my `overflow: auto;` isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in the long run, messing with height (150%, 200%) is going to affect your layout. I forked your JSFiddle, and changed the heights back to 100%. I also used `overflow-x: scroll`, which I think should solve your issue if I am understanding your question correctly.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/52gsf85c/

Comment: Yup you're right! That fixed it. Probably should have just added more menu items to test instead of messing with the heights. I'm using `overflow-y: auto;` and still worked.

Comment: Awesome! Good catch on the `y` vs `x`